# Use of US Dollar in Bahamas

Tags: money, bahamas

The Bahamian dollar is [exchanging 1 to 1 to the US Dollar](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bahamian%20dollar%20to%20usd).  On top of this a lot of Cruise Ships originating in the US make a stop at Nassau.

Does that mean that I can use US Dollars in Bahamas just as I do Bahamian ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.  US Dollars are accepted by most every business in the Bahamas and some places, such as casinos, only accept US Dollars.

Comment: Watch out though because you might pay with USD and then get change in Bahamian dollars so try not to use big bills if you can avoid.

Comment: Getting change is no big deal, you just have to make sure to use up your Bahamian Dollars before leaving the islands, as they are near impossible to exchange once you leave the islands.

Comment: that was my point in not using big bills.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahamian_dollar#Relationship_with_the_U.S._dollar) says that businesses in the Bahamas accept both Bahamian and US dollars. However, this is because they choose to do so and it's not an inevitable consequence of the exchange rate. Indeed, it's common for businesses in many parts of the world to accept multiple currencies even if there's no formal relationship between them: they do that because it is more convenient for them and their customers.